# How Much Resuablility can we have from Flutter (Dart Base Code) for Huawei- Harmony OS

Tags: flutter, harmonyos

I am working on Flutter with targets Android and iOS platform.

There is also requests coming in for Harmony OS.

Is it possible if we can reuse the Flutter Code to publish *.app file or can we utilize as wrapper to build solution separately for HarmonyOS App

Answer (score 1):

I believe HarmonyOS accepts `.apk` (like android) files. You just have to upload the release apk of your app to Huawei App Gallery. But if your app does in-app payment, you will have to do more research.

HarmonyOS, ColorOS, and so on are a subset of Android.